# how to set url in admin option page

Tags: urls

http://localhost/managingcode/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=invitation_code&page=invitationcode&create=action

How to set this ???
I have to create a from when click on button inside a option page

Answer (score 0):

You can only this link when you register a new post type with the right argument to show it in the admin ui and be available in the menu :

```
    $args = array(
       'show_ui'            => true,
       'show_in_menu'       => true,
    }
    register_post_type('invitation_code', $args);
```

There's no really need to have "page=invitation_code" as you are in an edit page.

If you need to create a special page for "invitation_code", your need to use `add_menu_page()` function.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/